# WAMP 2.5 hangs my Windows 7 SP1 laptop as soon as it starts

Tags: windows-7, freeze, localhost, wamp, wordpress

I am using WAMP 2.5 with local folder (localhost/websitename) setting.
Every time I open WAMP (when internet is connected) it hangs my laptop for a number of minutes and the only option I have, is to stop all services and close WAMP.

- I am using 32bit Windows 7 Ultimate SP1
- Apache is installed as a 'service'
- mod_rewrite is enabled in Apache
- I am on WordPress 4.0
- Using Simplicity theme
- The page that hangs the WAMP have a GravityForms form

Comment: Do you have to launch your Wordpress site to make it hang or is it just launching WAMPserver itself that hangs the PC?

Comment: WordPress site.

Comment: Did you install WP on WAMPServer or is this a copy of a live site to your local machine?

Comment: Copy of a live site.

Comment: You probably have not copied it correctly. You cannot just copy a WP database. See the WP site here for assitance http://codex.wordpress.org/Running_a_Development_Copy_of_WordPress

Comment: I properly backed-up the data. The DB and all the files are backed up via a plugin I am using for two years without any issue.

Comment: Ok so whats this, chopped liver?

Comment: I am sorry, what?

Comment: Suggestion: install [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler). That will allow you to watch all incoming and outgoing traffic when you start your browser and connect to your local WP site. If it is still calling out to the original site you shoud be able to see it happening.